# S3 bucket to bucket copy performance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to copy some files from one bucket to another (same region), getting speed of around 315mb/s. However I'm using it in lambda and there is a 15 min timeout limit. So for bigger files goes into timeout

Below is the code snippet I'm using (in python), is there any other way I can speed it up? any inputs are welcome.

```
 s3_client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    aws_session_token=session_token,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)

s3_client.copy(bucket_pair["input"], bucket_pair["output"]["Bucket"],
                               bucket_pair["output"]["Key"])
```

I saw many posts of passing chunksize and all, but I don't see them in ALLOWED_COPY_ARGS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a step function and iterate over all objects and copy them. To increase throughput you can use a map task

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html

If you don’t want to use stepfunction you can use one producer lambda to write all objects into a sqs queue and consume them from a lambda to copy them to the respective target.

A different option would be to use S3 object replication

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html

But I’m not sure if that fits for your use case

Comment: This is already in place. But when a single file is more than 500 gb that is when the timeout happens. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. Maybe it helps

Comment: got your point, but the use case is that, files which needs to be copied will come in sqs, not all the files from the bucket needs to be replicated. Thx.

Comment: Have a look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html#batch-replication-scenario